# ray.services.get_node_ip_address() doesn't work. ray cluster python

Tags: python, cluster-computing, ray

I am learning to use [ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/) on a cluster from [the official documentation](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/cluster/index.html)
I just wanted to test a single functionality which is `ray.services.get_node_ip_address()`, but I have the following error:

```
>>> import ray
>>> ray.services.get_node_ip_address()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'ray' has no attribute 'services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in `ray._private.services.get_node_ip_address()`

It seems that the location of `get_node_ip_address()` is changed from `ray.services.get_node_ip_address()` to `ray._private.services.get_node_ip_address()`